# Please explain the Semaphore counting scheme

Tags: c#, semaphore

In the following code:

```
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(3, 3);
    semaphore.WaitOne();
    int count = semaphore.Release();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Count = {count}");
```

I set the initial count to 3, then WaitOne() (decrement to 2) then I Release() (increment back to 3).

**So why is the count 2?**
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore.release?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Semaphore_Release) the `Release` method:

> Exits the semaphore and returns the previous count.

Meaning that calling it will result in the count that was available *before* you called `Release`.

Comment: OK.  I understand the count now according to the documentation, but how does this make sense?  Why would I want the previous count?  After I call Release(), I want to know if I've balanced out my Waits with my Releases.

Answer (score 1):

> Why would I want the previous count?

In short the current count is pointless, that value might have changed before you could do anything with it. So it instead (and rightly so) it gives you the only real source of truth it has, which is the previous count (when it was released).

If you really really want the current count you can query it via [NtQuerySemaphore](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FUndocumented%20Functions%2FNT%20Objects%2FSemaphore%2FNtQuerySemaphore.html) which is an undocumented Win API call. Though in truth you shouldn't need to rely on this, the mechanics of the semaphore is all that you should need in any normal usage.

Also you could probably make your own interlocked counter, but once again, this really shouldn't be necessary

Comment: What am I going to do with the 'previous' count?  There are only two places where the count is needed for something useful and that's when you've used up all your counts (count == 0), and when the count has returned to the initial count (count == initialCount).  In my case, I need to know when all the tasks that were gated by a semaphore have completed.

Comment: @DonaldAirey semaphore is about allowing access to a resource and blocking when the count it reached, thats it, if you have a use case where you want to do something with a non cpu cached count that you can do something with, then unfortunately you are going to have to implement such a structure yourself and use an interlocked value and or a locking mechanism to allow for thread safe concurrency. you could base such a structure off a semaphore if you will

Comment: *that value might have changed before you could do anything with it* I disagree.  You know it was **n** before you released it.  You know it was released.  So now you know that it is at least **n + 1**.  Where's the ambiguity?